# Laravel Forwarding Route To Another Route File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web, restful-architecture

I'm building enterprise modular Laravel web application but I'm having a small problem.

I would like to have it so that if someone goes to the /api/*/ route (/api/ is a route group) that it will go to an InputController. the first variable next to /api/ will be the module name that the api is requesting info from. So lets say for example: /api/phonefinder/find

In this case, when someone hit's this route, it will go to InputController, verifiy if the module 'phonefinder' exists, then sends anything after the /api/phonefinder to the correct routes file in that module's folder (In this case the '/find' Route..)

So:

/api/phonefinder/find - Go to input controller and verify if phonefinder module exists (Always go to InputController even if its another module instead of phonefinder)

/find - Then call the /find route inside folder Modules/phonefinder/routes.php

Any idea's on how to achieve this?

Comment: So you basically want a rewrite for the api routes. I suppose you can do that with an .htaccess file. Have a look [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-). Or any other article pertaining to mod_rewrite.

Comment: Any reason why you don't link to the module directly?

Comment: @kerbholz I want a script to verify if the module is available and the user is allowed to use it first before actually calling it, i guess a middleware would work for that as suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middlewares are designed for this purpose. You can create a middleware by typing

```
php artisan make:middleware MiddlewareName
```

It will create a middleware named 'MiddlewareName' under `namespace App\Http\Middleware;` path.

In this middleware, write your controls in the `handle` function. It should return `$next($request);` Dont change this part.

In your `Http\Kernel.php` file, go to `$routeMiddleware` variable and add this line:

```
'middleware_name' => \App\Http\Middleware\MiddlewareName::class,
```

And finally, go to your `web.php` file and set the middleware. An example can be given as:

```
Route::middleware(['middleware_name'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/phonefinder', 'SomeController@someMethod');
    });
});
```

Whenever you call `api/phonefinder` endpoint, it will go to the Middleware first.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is HMVC, where you can send internal route requests, but Laravel doesn't support it.

If you want to have one access point for your modular application then you should declare it like this (for example):

```
Route::any('api/{module}/{action}', 'InputController@moduleAction');
```

Then in your `moduleAction($module, $action)` you can process it accordingly, initialize needed module and call it's action with all attached data. Implement your own `Module` class the way you need and work from there.

Laravel doesn't support HMVC, you can't have one general route using other internal routes. And if those routes (`/find` in your case) are not internal and can be publicly accessed then also having one general route makes no sense.